# Jesus celebrated Jewish Passover; why Christians celebrate Easter, a different feast?

Tags: life-of-jesus, easter

According to the four Canonical gospels Jesus Christ and the apostles kept the Passover (John records three Passovers celebrated by Jesus: [John 2:13](http://biblehub.com/john/2-13.htm), [John 6:4](http://biblehub.com/john/6-4.htm), [John 11:55](http://biblehub.com/john/11-55.htm) ); Why  Christians today celebrate a different feast that appeared c. 150 AD, almost one century and a half later?

Comment: What research have you done? Surely you're aware that not all Christians are Jews?

Comment: I think this might also be case of semantics or something. In some countries Christians celebrate Passover in their native tongue (i.e the word used literally means Passover) but still call it Easter when referring to it in English. So, in some cases the word Easter has become synonymous with Passover, but the feast still surrounds the death and resurrection of Christ. Here is an article that might interest you: http://www.christiananswers.net/q-eden/edn-t020.html if you're into these kind of teachings.

Comment: You are giving Biblical quotes, so I assume that you know that Easter is about the resurrection of Jesus. That is entirely different from what is celebrated at Passover. So what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: Easter is a celebration of Jesus' resurrection. Passover is a celebration of the Exodus. Is this what you are confused on?

Comment: @curiousdannii I am not sure you can make that statement. To not understand that the last Passover meal links back to the Exodus and to the sacrifice of Isaac is to not understand anything. The change to a new feast was purely politics from Constantine.

Comment: I am asking because of the concept of precedent example.

Comment: I am asking because of the concept of the precedent example witch is very important in some religions (which I am aware of anyway) such as Judaism, Mandaeism, Islam, and Zoroastrianism. This means that any practice or doctrine not practiced by the the prophet(s) or mentioned in the holy scripture or related to such is considered an innovation and thus not an acceptable part of said religions.Jesus did observe Passover and did not specify a new feast, Easter for example. Thus Easter has no precedent example (not also practiced by his immediate disciples or specified by the Canonical gospels).

Comment: @iesouslufend Then the question you should ask is "How do Christians justify celebrating feasts that have no precedent example?" And direct this explicitly at Christians that do (most of them).

Answer (score 1):

Christians celebrate Easter because it marks the anniversary of Jesus' Resurrection, the sole reason Christianity even exists and the source of the joy of salvation for the Christian. It is *the* most important event in Christianity and, according to Christians, all of human history.

Passover is the oldest Jewish celebration. It celebrates the Exodus in general and specifically how the Lord's Angel of Death passed over the households with the blood of a lamb on its door posts, but proceeded into the households of the Egyptian and took the first born. Passover is also a sacrificial event. A lamb is slaughtered for every Jewish family, as God commanded.

Christian theology is rich with analogy about how the Passover represents Christ's death, which covers our sins and saves us from death. Easter is the completion of that theology, where even Christ, the perfect sacrifice, conquers death and rises to Glory.

Many Christians are not Jews. Every Christian I've heard of does not believe that sacrifice is necessary anymore. Christ was the final sacrifice. It seems odd that Christians would celebrate an event that has been superseded by another: Good Friday. Good Friday is the celebration of Christ's Passion (march to the Cross, in perfect submission to the Father). Tradition holds that this took place on Passover.

---

I suspect the wikipedia articles on [Passover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passover) and [Easter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter) would be helpful.